# java physics app in android ( maths )

Tags: java, android, eclipse, math

Basically, I'm new to java and I have to make an android application that can do simple physics equations such as I=Q*t.... etc etc, basically I cannot for the life of me get the result to output, has anyone got any idea's why this wont work on the emulator?

I have tried putting intents and all sorts in there. Help please

```
public class Current extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_current);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Intent intent = getIntent();
    }

        public void Main(String[]args){

        Button calc1 = (Button)findViewById(string.Calculate_Current);

        calc1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


             public void onClick(View v) {

                // IIIIII HATE JAVA

                EditText Charge1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number_input_2);    
                EditText Time1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number_input_3);
                TextView Distances_answer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Distances_answer);




                double charge = Double.parseDouble(Charge1.getText().toString());
                double Time = Double.parseDouble(Time1.getText().toString());

                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                Intent intent = new Intent();

                Distances_answer.setText("" + charge + Time);



            }
        });
```

Comment: I can't figure what you are trying? Are you trying to display result in new Activity or something else? You are instanced new Intent but you are not using them later ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like you are taking input of charge and time from two edittexts and then on click of a button you are updating a textview to place that product of charge and time there.Try this out

```
public class Current extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_name);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();


  Button calc1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttons_id_in_layout);

    calc1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


         public void onClick(View v) {

            EditText Charge1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number_input_2);    
            EditText Time1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number_input_3);
            TextView Distances_answer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.distances_answer);
            double charge = Double.parseDouble(Charge1.getText().toString());
            double time = Double.parseDouble(Time1.getText().toString());
//Time is a class in Java
            Distances_answer.setText("" +charge*time);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello, that has worked a treat, i should have explained better, i am attempting to do it like an equation triangle, in other words the user has three numberDecimal fields that can input to, once they click calculate, the program runs and then outputs the missing value. This will be spread over five different screens with multiple calculations on each. Thank you to the user above as this has finally outputted the correct answer, now i have to add conditions such as division and only outputting the missing field etc. thank you so much

Comment: Infact, is there a way, under the condition above, that you can tell the program to only find the missing value? irrespective of which values have been put in ?

Comment: glad to help :)! can you tell me exactly what are you doing with that triangle values? Is it like Pythagoras that user gives 2 sides and u have to calculate the third?

Comment: essentially yes, il make a new topic called Java physics traingles, with a few screen shots as an example if that would help? cheers

Comment: yeah and please be more descriptive this time:)